# Trouble embedding CSS in my simple HTML navigation bar code with external ways of embedding

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting, embed

So im new to coding and I was wonder if its possable to embed css into HTML. I looked it up and they said to use the external ways. They said to use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

but when I tried It didn't didn't do anything. I tried looking it up but was confused by all the the different ways and such. Here is my code.

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo"></h1>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
 </head>
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Work+Sans:400,600');
body {
 margin: 0;
 background: #222;
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 800;
}

.container {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #55d6aa;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;

  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;

  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

I know this seems like a stupid question and mabey it is but I could really use some hemp beucase I love coding and I really want to be able to have both Javascript and CSS in a HTML code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I am pretty sure what part is wrong but I don't know how to format it)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is and it's called Inline Styling but you do not want to do this as this will not only take longer to code for your website but will make it harder to make changes for your website - the reason why this isn't working is because your css and html need to be two separate files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

^ The reason why this doesn't work is because your css is in the same file as the html the html and css need to be separated in two files like this

(the above href path needs to refer to the path of your where your css file is located so if it is in the same directory as your html it will be href="mystyle.css" If not and is located in a folder it will be href:"/folder name/mystyle.css"):

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo"></h1>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
 </head>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Work+Sans:400,600');
body {
 margin: 0;
 background: #222;
 font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 800;
}

.container {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #55d6aa;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 23px;

  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #444;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;

  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Secondly, I'm not sure if you have noticed but your code only has a head tag, usually a website requires a head, body and footer for it to function normally.

Looking at this quite simple to fix.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<title>Website Name</title> 
</head>
<header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
 </header>
```

Your link ref needed to be at the top of the page, you didn't include a title, you needed to include the characters you are using for the page and there you go you have what should be functioning code I believe.